# Kafka python AvroConsumer seek method

Tags: python, apache-kafka, avro, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

I am having issues consuming from a given offset using python, in Java I had implemented a KafkaConsumer and used

`consumer.seek(new TopicPartition(topic, 0), 3)`

to consume from my third offset in partition 0.

But when using Python I am using an AvroConsumer, which has a seek method but only takes the partition as a parameter and not an offset to consume from. it seems to consume then from the beginning of the topic. Is there a way with AvroConsumer to consume from a certain offset?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you provide the offset as a parameter when creating the topic partition.

I don't have an example of your code to model this off of so I'll just write it like this.

```
confluent_kafka.TopicPartition(topic,
                               partition,
                               offset)

consumer.seek(tp)
```

This is based on the integration test in the library for this code. I have highlighted the relevant test and linked below

> [Integration Test For Confluent Kafka Python](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/d874996081cad657135acf89d6ddba2b50e93dc2/examples/integration_test.py#L556-L579)

Comment: Correct thank you! Any idea where I can look at the AvroConsumer class I couldn't find it when I was looking

Comment: Feel free to check out my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53558646/avroconsumer-consume-from-timestamp-using-offsets-for-times :)